# Laravel - Target class [app\Http\Controllers\ProductsController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, class, routes

I tried several stackoverflow solutions for my problem, but none could fix the problem.

When i open my Laravel-Project and route to  /products, i get the message:
"Target class [app\Http\Controllers\ProductsController] does not exist".

Here are pictures of my code:

**web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use app\Http\Controllers\ProductsController;

Route::get('/products', [ProductsController::class, 'index']);
```

**Controller.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('products.index');
    }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Products</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is a picture of my filestructure:**
[laravel structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElZGB.jpg)

Would be so nice if you could help me, cause i really need to go on with my laravel tutorial.

Comment: in addition: the ProductsController.php highlights the "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" in grey like not used.

Comment: did you run the command `composer dump-autoload`? also add your composer.json to your question

Comment: probably a typo, try `use App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController;` `app` should be `App`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hy again,
thanks to **sta**´s comment i could solve the problem:

"probably a typo, try use App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController; app should be App"

Before(not working):

```
use app\Http\Controllers\ProductsController;
```

Solution:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController;
```

iggivannaz

Comment: A problem caused by a typo is off-topic. Just delete the question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was using PHP short tag and it was not activated on server.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34687034)

Comment: As I mentioned this solution solved my issue, we replaced the `<?` with `<PHP?`... and I didn't get the minus score!?